# AJAX calls fail when the base URL is set

Tags: 7, ajax, configuration

I have installed the Drupal 7.17 security update, and I am having some issues with my site.

If I comment out the `$base_url ='www.xxx.com';` line in the setting.php file, the AJAX calls work; when I uncomment that line, the AJAX calls fail.

What could be the reason behind this? how can I get my base_url working again?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't already include a base URL in your ajax link. For my development site, `http://localhost/project1/ajaxlink`, the following will work perfectly when no base URL has been set.

```
$.ajax({url: 'project1/ajaxlink', ...
```

In case a base URL has been set, the AJAX call is equivalent to the following, which will not work.

```
$.ajax({url: 'project1/project1/ajaxlink', ...
```

Comment: '#ajax' => array(
        'callback'=>'contact_form_alters_submit_callback'),   i used default path in ajax system/ajax. my ajax are working correctly on localhost, but it will not woring on live server, if i bypass the folder name of my website on live server using $base_url.

Comment: @sarfraz did you checked the error showing in console?

Comment: thanks sir, your reply, solved my problem adding rewrite rule in htaccess file.